# Foregin key constraint cannot be implemented - Odoo v9 community

Tags: python, odoo

I'm adding a related field from `product.product` into `stock.picking` model, on Odoo v9 community.

Like this:

```
class StockPicking(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.picking'

    price_unity = fields.Float(string="Precio", store=True, readonly=True, related="product_id.price")
```

But it seems like it can't relate those fields, at least to show them, there is some incompatibility there,

And it throws me this error:

```
2016-10-18 14:14:34,202 24998 ERROR argentina openerp.modules.registry: Failed to load registry
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 386, in new
openerp.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 334, in load_modules
force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 237, in load_marked_modules
loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 137, in load_module_graph
init_module_models(cr, package.name, models)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0/openerp/modules/module.py", line 300, in init_module_models
result = obj._auto_init(cr, {'module': module_name})
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0/openerp/api.py", line 250, in wrapper
return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0/openerp/models.py", line 2548, in _auto_init
cr.execute('ALTER TABLE "%s" ALTER COLUMN "%s" TYPE %s' % (self._table, k, c[2]), log_exceptions=False)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0/openerp/sql_db.py", line 141, in wrapper
return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov9/odoo-9.0/openerp/sql_db.py", line 220, in execute
res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
ProgrammingError: foreign key constraint "stock_picking_price_unit_fkey" cannot be implemented
DETAIL:  Key columns "price_unit" and "id" are of incompatible types: numeric and integer.
```

Any ideas on how can I relate that product `price` field into `stock.picking`?

On `stock.move` it works, but there is something here that I can't see.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a problem with *price_unit* field. *stock.picking* object don't have *product_id* and you are making related field with *product_id* That's why it's raise as *ProgrammingError* You should take values from the *picking lines*

Comment: Yes, but move_line doesn't have the product price, so I don't know

Comment: As your previous question adds *price* in *stock.move* object. Correct ? If yes, then you can directly access. You need to browse *move_line* and take your desire value from there.

Comment: I found a way, but I have some other kind of issue with the view, gonna open a new question for that

Comment: How can you even relate one price (picking, your wish) to more than one price (multiple moves, odoo default)? Are you trying to get an average price or something like that?

Comment: Exactly, that's the error I got, I need to add it to the lines, but I'm going to open a new question for it

Comment: This is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40118981/invalid-view-definition-odoo-v9-community Thank You