# Invalid view definition - Odoo v9 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9, qweb

I manage to find a way to have the product price on `stock.picking`, but now I have a view error.

This is my  model:

```
from openerp import models, fields, api
import openerp.addons.decimal_precision as dp 

class StockPicking(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.picking'

    product_id = fields.Many2one("product.product", "Product")
    price_unity = fields.Float(string="Precio", store=True, readonly=True, related="product_id.lst_price")
```

Now, the offending code in my view:

```
<record id="view_stock_picking_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Stock Picking Price Form</field>
    <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_picking_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//page/field[@name='pack_operation_product_ids']/tree/field[@name='qty_done']" position="after">
                <field name="price_unity"/>
            </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```

It says `Error details:
Field`price_unity`does not exist` how is this even possible?

On tree view it doesn't throws this error:

```
<record id="view_stock_picking_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Stock Picking Price Tree</field>
    <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.vpicktree"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="state" position="before">
            <field name="price_unity"/>
        </field>
    </field> 
</record>
```

So, how is it that in form view I can't declare it'

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know you mentioned that you do not get an error in your list view. Do the values appear as expected in the list view?

Comment: Let me comment the form and update, I'll write back

Comment: Yes, it shows the values expected, but only tree view, on form it throws the error and cannot install it

Comment: It shows them when I create and save the record, but if I update it it remains the same value :/

Comment: What happens if you remove `store=True`

Comment: Yes, now it updates the values, cool :), but can't figure out what's wrong in the form

Comment: This is unusual. I have to assume you have included your `.py` file in `__init__.py` otherwise I do not think your tree view would work. This is often the cause of an error like this. I wonder if it is something related to your `xpath`. I wouldn't think so, but maybe replace the field in your xpath with `<h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>` just to see if you xpath places the content in the correct spot. I would love to know why this is not working for you. But I see no reason why it would work for list and not form.

Comment: Okay, Ill try it :), yes, I think it has to do with how stock module has it's views declared though, I'll try and write you back, Thank You

Comment: Good luck, I am at a loss. What you are saying would be much more sensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding *price_unity* field in view inside *pack_operation_product_ids* field.

*pack_operation_product_ids* is a One2many relation type with *stock_pack_operation* object.

So we need to add/register *price_unity* field in *stock_pack_operation* object.

Try with following code:

```
class StockPackOperation(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.pack.operation'

    price_unity = fields.Float(string="Precio", store=True, readonly=True, related="product_id.lst_price")

    #product_id is already in table so no need to add/register
```

Afterwards restart Odoo server and upgrade your custom module.

NOTE:

You are not getting error in tree of Stock Picking because you have added/registered *price_unity*.

Your view code is good.

Comment: Awesome! Lol, Thank You very much!